# Is it possible to animate anything with natural way in Unity or smt else?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I m wondering that if is it possible to animate anything along the rules of physics.

I mean, i have a cube, and two legs attached to that cube. I want to just animate that legs one after each other, but unity or other software will force its animation system to behave to my animated legs to make my cube walk. I wont change positions for  my body(cube) but legs will do that.

demonstration:
https://streamable.com/dda610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this animation type is called procedural animation. You base your animations dynamically based on physics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_animation

good video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNidsMesxSE

tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Wh6fzSl_u8

Answer (score 2):

Physically based animation is a complex task. You can use the timeline to animate legs but they won't work too well physically. You probably want to use code to keep the body a fixed height above the surface and use the timeline editor to animate the legs. Or perhaps keep the body at the same height and use 'inverse kinematics' to move the legs in a more realistic fashion. Neither of these options will be very quick for you to start using really effectively if you have very little experience with unity or with code but knowing what to look up is half the battle of learning.